# React-admin: Combine pessimistic mutationMode with redirect false

Tags: react-admin

Trying in my edit pages to set mutationMode="pessimistic" and redirect={false} as I want the behavior of staying on the same page on save, but without the possibility to undo changes. Problem is when I do a change and hit save the old record's values are showing. How can I force the new values to be shown instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application for Create is described here, but apparently for Edit it will be similar:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Create.html#save-and-add-another

Comment: Sounds like a custom save button is a great start! Not sure how to make the page load with the new saved record though? Tried to invalidate the cache of the previous record. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using useRefresh() from react-admin.